# Is posible to know if a certain Thread is alive?

Tags: java, multithreading

for my purposes of html parsing,  I have implemented a PRODUCER/CONSUMER PATTERN. MY problem is the way in wich I can stop the consumer after that a producer have finished the task and a condivised buffer is emtpy . 
EXAMPLE:

I have one PRODUCER and 5 CONSUMER. The producer stop to work because have complished its tasks. So the Consumer how can know that the producer has finished its work??
 I have try to implement:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class MainTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BlockingQueue queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>( );



    Producer p = new Producer(queue,"0");
   // FOR ALL CONSUMER I PASS THE REFERENCE TO THE UNIQUE PRODUCER !!!
    Consumer c1=new Consumer(queue,"1",p);
    Consumer c2=new Consumer(queue,"2",p);
   Consumer c3=new Consumer(queue,"3",p);
   Consumer c4=new Consumer(queue,"4",p);
    Consumer c5=new Consumer(queue,"5",p);

    p.start();

     c1.start();c2.start();c3.start();c4.start();c5.start();


  }
}
THE PRODUCER:
class Producer extends Thread{

      BlockingQueue<String> queue;

      public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> queue, String s) {
          super ("THREAD"+s);
        this.queue = queue;
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void run(){
        int messagecode = 1;


 boolean flagLavora= true;
        //ciclo infinito
        while(flagLavora ){
          try {
              System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");


              System.out.println(" : IS ALIVE "+Thread.currentThread().isAlive()+" ");
              System.out.println(" IS INTERRUPTED "+Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()+" ");

                  System.out.println( this.getName()+">>"+"PRODUTT  Thread");

                System.out.println("Producing "+(++messagecode));

                     queue.put("MESSAGE@"+messagecode);

                       System.out.println(messagecode+" in queue");
                System.out.println("SIZE QUEUE:"+queue.size());


                if (messagecode %9==0) 
                 { 
                    System.out.println(  "STATE PRODUTT "+ Thread.currentThread().getState());
                    System.out.println( this.getName()+">>PRODUTT CLOSE");
                    System.out.println(  "IS ALIVE:"+ this.currentThread().isAlive());

                    flagLavora= false;


                }
              System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");


                sleep(1000);



          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

  System.out.println(  "\n \n EXIT CICLE WHILE \n \n");

      }

THE CONSUMER:
class Consumer extends Thread{

      static int id;
      static Producer produttore=null;
      int code=0;
      BlockingQueue<String> queue;

      public Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> queue,String nameThread, Producer p) {

      super ("THREADN_ "+nameThread);
      this.produttore=p;
      this.queue = queue;
      code=++id;

      }

      public void run(){

        while(true){
          try {


              System.out.println("\n -------------------------------------------------------------");


              System.out.println("CONSUM "+this.getName()+":"+queue.size()+" SIZE QUEUE");
          if (produttore==null){




            stop();


      }         

          else   if (   produttore.getState().compareTo(State.RUNNABLE) ==0  || queue.size()!=0){



     System.out.println( this.getName()+">> "+code+" waiting for the message...");

        String message = queue.take();
        System.out.println("Thread:"+code+" --> "+message+" taken!");

       if (   produttore.getState().compareTo(State.RUNNABLE) ==0  ||  produttore!=null){
          System.out.println("NULL PRODUTTORE + RUNNABLE");

     System.out.println("CONSUMATORE:"+Thread.currentThread().getName()  +"  CHIUDE  \n");
    System.out.println("CONTENUTO PRODUTTORE: "+produttore==null);


        stop();


 }

  System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------- \n ");


        //riposa 2 secondi
     sleep(2000);   



         }

         else {

             sleep(1000);  
         }




      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("PROBLEMI CONSUMATORE:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
    }
  }
```

---

SO I would like Know how to implement the scenario in while, The producer complished the task to add on a queue strings, and when finished, die, and the consumer works until there is something in the queue condivided and the consumer is alive.

Who could help me??
THANKS

Comment: -1 - for not putting in the effort to format your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand.

You could use the [Thread.IsAlive()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) method to know if your Producer Thread is still alive.

Your `while` will look like this :

```
while(produttore.isAlive() || !queue.isempty())
```

Comment: But.... When the PRODUCER= produttore, is died, with the condition if messagecode%==0..I don't know why when I do produdttore.State(), print RUNNABLE..InmeanWhile is died...WHY??

Comment: THANKS you very much for your suggestion,I have modified the cicle with:
while(produttore.isAlive() || !queue.isEmpty() && produttore !=null)
And now ALL WORKS!!! ^_^

Comment: @Bomberlatinos9: **IFF** you really to check for *produttore != null* then do it **BEFORE** checking for *produttore.isAlive()* because the way you've written your code, it's unlikely to have useful semantics.  Make it *while( produttore != null && produttore.isAlive() || !queue.isEmpty)*.  Something like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to approach the problem in a different way. Instead of a blocking queue, create an `Executor` (use the [helper methods in `Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)).

Then for each task, let the producer submit a task to the executor. Now you can simply wait for the executor to terminate after the producer has submitted all tasks (`ExecutorService.awaitTermination()`).

Comment: Sounds like a good usecase for http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html.